# I am new to virtual environments and successfully installed virtualenv-win through CMD....aslo created an environment named ( Samim )

Tags: python, django, cmd, virtualenv

After creating the environment I accidently closed cmd.
now I want to reopen the ( Samim ) environment but cant find the command to reopen it , please help me.
I tried to check if that envionment existed or nor by typing "lsvirtualenv"
it returned

```
dir /b /ad "C:\Users\User\Envs"
================================================
Samim
```

So it is present in the system , how can I activate this env ?

Comment: You write `workon Samim`?

Comment: cd C\Users\User\Envs\Samim and once you are inside the env type .\Scripts\activate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can activate the virtual environment in a Windows command prompt with:

```
workon envname
```

So you can change the directory with:

```
cd "C\Users\User\Envs"
```

and then write:

```
workon Samim
```

Answer (score 0):

For activating a virtualenv in windows direct you cmd to the folder containing the environment and type the following command

```
environment_name\Scripts\activate
```

Remember to cd to the folder containing the Env one